# How to display time ago like Youtube in Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm writing a Angular app to clone some YouTube functionalities using data from an API.

The app fetches video timestamp as a String from an API

Each timestamp has this format :

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
```

One example would be:

```
2021-04-28 13:18:20.13
```

I would like to display in a text or cardview as  :

```
1 hour
1 hours ago
4 weeks ago
11 months ago
1 year ago
...
```

How can I achieve this is Angular without using a library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by building my very own user-friendly Date Pipe. Use the command in a terminal window `ng g p pipes/DateAgo` to use the Angular CLI to generate Custom Date Pipe inside the pipes folder.

Now the generate file structure will have two. Feel free to delete the `date-ago.pipe.spec.ts` file, if you do not care about testing.

Now inside the `date-ago.pipe.ts` file, write this code.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'dateAgo',
    pure: true
})
export class DateAgoPipe implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        if (value) {
            const seconds = Math.floor((+new Date() - +new Date(value)) / 1000);
            if (seconds < 29) // less than 30 seconds ago will show as 'Just now'
                return 'Just now';
            const intervals = {
                'year': 31536000,
                'month': 2592000,
                'week': 604800,
                'day': 86400,
                'hour': 3600,
                'minute': 60,
                'second': 1
            };
            let counter;
            for (const i in intervals) {
                counter = Math.floor(seconds / intervals[i]);
                if (counter > 0)
                    if (counter === 1) {
                        return counter + ' ' + i + ' ago'; // singular (1 day ago)
                    } else {
                        return counter + ' ' + i + 's ago'; // plural (2 days ago)
                    }
            }
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

Finally, don’t forget to import our Custom Date Pipe in `app.modules.ts` file and add it to the declarations: `[...DateAgoPipe]` array. (Do this if you did not use the Angular CLI to generate the Date Pipe, otherwise the import should already be there as Angular CLI does it for you.)

Now, just update the HTML code from `<p>Published: {{dog.date | date}}</p>` to `<p>Published: {{dog.date | dateAgo}}</p>` and watch the magic happen.

Comment: You may need to update `intervals[i]` depending upon your TypeScript configuration/Angular version. For example: `counter = Math.floor(seconds / intervals[i as keyof typeof intervals]);`

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a date from string:
const date = new Date('2021-04-28T13:18:20.13')

// create date for now:
const today = new Date();

// then calculate the difference:
const difference = today.getTime() - date.getTime();
```

you'll get the time difference in milliseconds. then you can write a formula to calculate the years, months, days etc. from there.